# Имитация нажатия клавиш (русские символы)

Tags: c#, winapi

Вот с помощью WinApi имитирую нажатия клавиш

```
public class KeyOperations
{

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

    public static void SendKey(char key)
    {
        keybd_event((byte)key, 0, 0, 0);
        keybd_event((byte)key, 0, 0x2, 0);

    }
}
```

Потом имитирую так

```
KeyOperations.SendKey('E');
```

Так вот этот способ не работает, если буквы маленькие, а так же русские символы. Как сделать полную имитацию нажатия, что бы можно использовать символы как русского, так и английского алфавита?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class KeyOperations
{
    private const byte KEYUP = 0x2;
    private const byte KEYDOWN = 0x0;
    private const byte VK_SHIFT = 0x10;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern short VkKeyScan(char ch);

    public static void SendKey(char key)
    {
        byte Vcode = (byte)VkKeyScan(key);

        if (char.IsUpper(key))
        {
            keybd_event(VK_SHIFT, 0, KEYDOWN, 0);
            keybd_event(Vcode, 0, KEYDOWN, 0);
            keybd_event(Vcode, 0, KEYUP, 0);
            keybd_event(VK_SHIFT, 0, KEYUP, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            keybd_event(Vcode, 0, KEYDOWN, 0);
            keybd_event(Vcode, 0, KEYUP, 0);
        }
    }
}
```